# Try update Ubuntu 14 to 16 and reboot --> no more ssh / ufw don't work / no ping

Tags: 14.04, server, updates, ssh

I'm pretty desperate.
This week I try an update for my distant server from ubunut 14 to ubuntu 16 with : 
`/opt/psa/bin/distupgrade.helper.ubt14-ubt16.x64.sh`
Then the tuto say reboot so I reboot.

```
php7.0-fpm start/running, process 25291
Please reboot the server and run the following command /opt/psa/bin/distupgrade.helper.ubt14-ubt16.x64.sh to continue.
STOP Distupgrade
```

Now :

- ping don't return 
  [ScreenShoot of shh -vvv host@IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFexe.png)
- ssh say connection TimeOut

When I launch rescue mode and access via ssh to a linux image (I choose an ubuntu 14) on my distant server :

- **ufw  status** :`` iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist ``
- **uname - a** : `Linux 62-210-253-46 4.2.0-35-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 16:37:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- **lsb_release -a** : `No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
  Release:        14.04
  Codename:       trusty`
- **ls -lh /lib/module** : `total 8,0K drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K avril 30 09:55
  3.13.0-169-generic drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K juil. 23  2015 3.13.0-58-generic`
- In **syslog** I have a message : `apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/run/systemd/journal/dev-log" p`

And as I said, I was in an update process, so after the reboot I have to re launch the command `/opt/psa/bin/distupgrade.helper.ubt14-ubt16.x64.sh` so I'm a bit afraid of install stuff like `apt-get install lsb-core`

Also when I connect with rescue mode I do :

````
```sudo su
mountall.sh 
chroot /mnt/sda1 bin/bash ```
````

And then all the command above

Many many many thanks for your help !

Comment: The standard release-upgrade tool is `do-release-upgrade` or `update-manager` as found in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is the name (though Ubuntu Core has *yy* format names, eg. Ubuntu Core 16 being an IoT release).  Ubuntu 4.2 kernel ended support in 2016.July, and Ubuntu does not have the 'plesk' tool you tried to use to upgrade, so possibly you should seek help via plesk.

Comment: You mean re-post on a plesk forum ?

Comment: You understand that I want to update my OS server and note the plesk soft ? Or There something I've not understood. 
By the way, how did you know I use plesk ?

Comment: Yes I do understand you're wanting to release-upgrade your box, however you're not using Ubuntu's provided, tested tools, but instead a non-Ubuntu (plesk) script, which is why I'm suggesting seeking help from them.

Comment: Ok I've got it , thanks for help @guiverc :)